# C# convert Date to text in cell in Excel (interop)

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a pretty specific problem with the "Automatic data conversions" that Excel is doing. First I'll try to explain what exactly I'm doing and how Excel is making fun of me ;)

My program is creating a Charts for reports from temperature sensors. In the reports the first Column is the date of the reading and the second column is the reading of the sensors for that date. The problem is the automatic selection of the "XAxis series" that Excel is doing, if the first column is in DateTime format:

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byub5fWTQ5hPTGZoWlJISkZrczA) is the example for what Excel is doing with the Charts if it "smells" Date format...

And [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byub5fWTQ5hPa0ZRd2VSbkNjMkU) is how the chart looks if the first column is in Text format.

I tried some variants to convert the values in the first column but everything is too slow or messes up the values. 
So far the "fastest" way that I found is:

```
foreach(Range cell in firstCol.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Value is DateTime && !(cell.Value).ToString().Contains("\'"))
            {
               cell.Value = "\'" + cell.Value;
            }
        }
```

But that's not fast enough. Imagine a 100 sheets (1 sheet for each sensor) and each sheet with between 2500 and 4000 rows.

I tried things like:

```
usedRange.NumberFormat = "@";
```

as it was suggested in a couple of places on internet but that doesn't work for Date formats. It converts this:
 01/12/2016 00:30 like this: 42705.02083.

So my question is if someone can suggest a better or faster way to convert the dates or to make Excel read the DateTime as text without messing up anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way by fixing the X axis itself, but if all your looking for is to get the date in text format, the quick fix would be something like:

```
=TEXT(DATE(2016,1,12)+TIME(0,30,0),"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```

Comment: Actually I've probably searched the entire internet about how to fix the x axis in that particular way but I didn't find anything. And I'm talking about one option that would fix my entire problem with one line if it existed.   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byub5fWTQ5hPNGpUckhtZkVKYjQ  That's the option I'm talking about. If anyone has any idea how to do something with that option in C# code, let me know, please.